# Javascript Behavior when Function.prototype.bind is called serially

Tags: javascript, bind

I have a question about Function.prototype.bind.

```js
function f() {
  return this;
}

const g=f.bind({foo:'foo'});
const h=g.bind({bar:'bar'});

console.log(h());    // expected {bar:'bar'} but get {foo:'foo'}
```

I was expecting the above snippet to produce either `{foo,bar}` or `{bar}` but instead I get `{foo}`.

Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: Bound functions cannot be rebound.

Comment: Calling `bind()` creates a new function that will ignore its `this` argument. No matter what you pass to that function, or `.bind()` it again, it's ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.bind()` to create a function that "fixes" the value of `this` in the called function results in a function where `this` *cannot* be overridden.

What you get back from `.bind()` is a new function that will pass along arguments to the original target function, with a guarantee that in that called function the value of `this` will be what you ask for. Re-binding that function therefore does no good: you do get back a new function, but it calls a function (the first bound function) that explicitly ignores its own `this` value.